# Compiling PHP with extensions

Tags: php, compilation, php-5.3, mbstring

Can anyone give me any pointers on why the following **./configure** settings do not appear to actually affect my build of PHP?

Details:

- php-5.3.5
- Compiling in order to use **php-cgi** on a per-domain basis

For example, my **./configure** looks like this:

```
./configure --with-curl --enable-mbstring
```

The **make, make install** works fine, and I successfully get my **php-cgi** binary. When I run:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

I can see that I am running 5.3.5, but there is no sign of **curl** or **mbstring**.

However, there is a catch: If I use run **phpize** on the extension directly (in the source) and go through a proper **./configure, make, make install**, I can add:

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

to my **php.ini** and then I see **mbstring** in my phpinfo() output.

What I surmise from this is that I can put in the extra effort to manually compile each and every extension I want, but I cannot get the extensions to compile in directly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: first dummy rule : **did you restart your apache?** if you are testing via a web page. Secondly, try `PATH/php -m`, and `PATH/php -i grep config`, both are tally? lastly, make sure you are access the correct php binaries

Comment: I got the same problem. I build some extension with source code under ext folder, some extension is successfully loaded by php, but only **curl** and **mbstring** can not be loaded. Anybody knows why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajreal's comment pointed me in the right direction.

I was trying a few things all at the same time and ended up crossing a few wires. I was not successful at creating a symbolic link to the **php-cgi** binary, so it had been copied to:

```
/var/www/vhost/DOMAIN/bin.
```

It was still pointing to the correct php.ini, but was not the same binary as what I had later compiled with the additional extensions.

Now it makes sense why modules added in the **php.ini** showed up but were not directly compiled in. Lesson learned!